# How to check that scroll is end of bottom in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

```
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('reached bottom');
    }
  }
```

It is working of this code as above, but it occured many times even not reached exactly end of bottom.

How to check wheather scroll is reached to end of bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY === document.body.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('bottom');
 }
```

I found it.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event) {
    // 200 is the height from bottom from where you want to trigger the infintie scroll, which can also be zero to detect bottom of window
    if ((document.body.clientHeight + window.scrollY + 200) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        console.log('triggred');
    }
  }
```